# MongoDB: How to find one result in third-sub array?

Tags: mongodb

This is my document.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "exportadores", 
    "instancia" : ISODate("2018-03-23T11:36:32.296+0000"), 
    "dwFatPDFs" : {
            "regis" : [
                {
                    "cod" : "A1", 
                    "idFat" : NumberLong(15772), 
                    "data" : ISODate("2018-04-13T12:33:44.149+0000"), 
                    "ipPm" : "192.168.0.1"
                }, 
                {
                    "cod" : "A2", 
                    "idFat" : NumberLong(15772), 
                    "data" : ISODate("2018-04-13T13:54:26.477+0000"), 
                    "ipPm" : "192.168.0.1"
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

I'd like to get one result from array(regis) by the 'cod'.

For example. If search "cod" like "A1"
I want to get something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "exportadores",
    "dwFatPDFs" : {
            "regis" : [
                {
                    "cod" : "A1", 
                    "idFat" : NumberLong(15772), 
                    "data" : ISODate("2018-04-13T12:33:44.149+0000"), 
                    "ipPm" : "192.168.0.1"
                }             
            ]
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for my english.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the dotted notation + the `$` identifier to return the first sub documents that match the condition :

```
Collection.find({
    "dwFatPDFs.regs.cod": your_id
}, {
    "dwFatPdfs.regs.$.cod": 1
});
```

I think this query will do the job

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, in this case: Should i use for example?

Collection.find({
    "dwFatPDFs.regis.cod": "A1"
}, {
    "dwFatPdfs.regis.$.cod": 1
});

Comment: Yes your query seems good